# How much money should I save in an account paying 5% interest compounded monthly if I want to have $6,000 in 6 months?

Tags: calculus

How much money should I save in an account paying 5% interest compounded monthly if I want to have $ 6,000 in 6 months ?

Comment: Find the correct formula, then plug and chug.

Comment: Are you saving each month, too, or are you putting a lump sum into the account at the beginning of the six months?

Comment: where are you getting an interest rate like that??

Comment: @Jonathan Meh, just wanted to ask that...

Comment: http://i40.tinypic.com/333y62b.png

Answer (score 2):

Using the formula:

$$A = p(1 + \frac{r}{n})^{nt}$$

where:

$\bullet$ $A$ = Amount = 6000

$\bullet$ $r$ = Rate = 5 % = 0.05

$\bullet$ $t$ = Time = 6 months

$\bullet$ $n$ = Monthly = 12

$\bullet$ $p$ = Principal = Unknown

We have:

$$6000 = p(1 + \frac{.05}{12})^{72}$$

Solving yields $p = \$4447.68$

Regards.

Comment: Actually, in the US at least, the "5% compounded monthly" usually means $n=12$.  But that might be a regionalism

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I started with it that way and changed it! Thanks and regards!

Comment: Seems students get tripped up with these kinds of questions when first learning interest/compounding, etc.! Good work!

Comment: @amWhy: Agreed and the financial industry doesn't help by creating every imaginable permutation! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Recall the formula for compound interest:

$$\text{Initial}\times(1+\text{Increase})^{n},$$

Where $n$ is the number of months. So in this case we have $\text{Increase}=0.05$, $n=6$ and we are trying to find $\text{Initial}$. Algebraically:

$$\text{Initial}\times1.05^{6}=\$6,000 \implies \text{Initial}=\frac{\$6,000}{1.05^{6}}=\$4,477.29$$

I hope this helps!

Comment: Usually, "5% compounded each month" really means "5%/12 each month, compunded." That is, the "5%" is a yearly number. At least here in the USA.

Answer (score 1):

$$ 6000 = P (1.05)^6 \implies P = \frac{6000}{(1.05)^6} $$

Run that through your calculator.